# subprocess.Popen() launches two process instead of one

Tags: python, subprocess, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project using the raspberry-pi and would like to detect a button push on the pi to launch a program (squeezelite https://code.google.com/p/squeezelite/) and then when the button is pushed again kill the program using the PID captured when the program is launched. I think the python subprocess module is a good choice for this, however, I am having a problem which I can't resolve.

The code:

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(['squeezelite','-o','sysdefault:CARD=ALSA','-n','test','-m', '01:00:00:00:00:03','-z'])
```

seems to launch two processes:

```
2886 pts/0   Z+    0:00 [squeezelite] defunct

2887 ?       SLsl  0:00 squeezelite -o sysdefault:CARD=ALSA -n test -m 01 00 00 00 00 03 -z
```

and proc.pid returns the PID of the the first one.

If I call proc.communicate() then the first process is cleaned up and I am left with only the second one, which by the way is the one I want. However, I am left with not knowing the PID of the second process (because proc.pid gives me the first one which is now gone). So I am not able to use the PID in a kill command.

I have tried various combinations of subprocess.Popen with different options (eg string argument, parameter argument, shell=True, shell=False) and each one gives a similar result.

Can anyone assist me in getting this to work? Or is the a better way to launch a program and at some later time kill it?

Thanks
aussieW

Comment: It's called a zombie process: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process I'm not sure if you should delete it.

Comment: What distribution are you using? You can use its daemonizing tools to simplify what you have to do with python. For instance, [instructions for Debian](http://forums.slimdevices.com/showthread.php?98152-HOWTO-Install-squeezelite-for-logitech-media-server-on-Debian-Squeeze-as-a-service).

Comment: I understand that the first process becomes a zombie process and is cleaned up by the calling proc.communicate(). My question is why are there two processes created when I really only wanted one, and the one I wanted was the second one NOT the first one.

Comment: I don't know squeezelite, but you are calling it with the `daemonize` switch, which probably forks the second process in the background.

Comment: Paulo Almeida - The distribution I am using is raspyfi which I am pretty sure is based on wheezy. What I want to do is launch and kill up to three separate instances of squeezelite using three separate push buttons. Do you think the daemonizing tools are suitable for that task?

Comment: Paulo Almeida - Thanks that was the answer. If I leave off the '-z' switch it behaves as I want it to.

Comment: Cool. You can still look into start-stop-daemon to take care of start/stop, but it will be more complex than the guide I linked, since you need three separate processes.

Comment: Paulo Almeida - After making the changes in my code I notice that while it does now only launch a single process, my main program now waits for the process to finish before moving continuing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, now it's not daemonizing :) See how start-stop-daemon works in the guide I linked. You will have to run it once for each process you want and save the PID in a different file. I think that's the simplest solution, without having to write it yourself in python.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida you can post you comment as an answer...

Comment: @SaulloCastro I considered that, but thought it was too much about systems administration and not enough programming. I suppose I should though, because this is getting long and can't go to chat.

Answer (score 1):

You are using squeezelite's `-z` option, which daemonizes the process. This explains why an additional process is being created. I think the best solution is to use the OS daemonizing tools (eg. start-stop-daemon), simplifying the calls you do with Python. There is a [guide about daemonizing squeezelite in Debian squeeze](http://forums.slimdevices.com/showthread.php?98152-HOWTO-Install-squeezelite-for-logitech-media-server-on-Debian-Squeeze-as-a-service), which can help get you started.

You need to start the process and save its PID in a file, so you can stop it later. One approach might be to use a daemon script that takes two parameters: start/stop and an identifier for your button.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I ended up getting it to work by removing the -z switch from the arguments I was passing in the Popen call.